# Can I Use Stored Gasoline?

Tags: gasoline

I have 3 cans of gasoline, stored in a shed, here in the south, since last summer.  Can the gas be safely used in my 2014 Chevy Cruze?

Comment: If you're just looking to get rid of the gasoline, I'd mix it with good gas that's already in the tank, but it's probably not a good idea to run your engine purely off the year-old gas.

Comment: As per the other comment - mix it to a half full tank or half empty whichever...